# How To Set Default Language for Android app?

Tags: java, android

I've created an app in two languages. The second one (english), is used when user's default system language is english. If it's not, then the first one is used.

I want to set the second language (that's english) as a DEFAULT language,
which means that when user opens my app and his system language is not the first one, nor English, the English language will appear as a default one.

I tried:

```
    Locale locale = new Locale("en_US");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    context.getApplicationContext.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

But got "context cannot be resolved" error everytime.. Is this piece of code right or..?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that. Whatever resources you put in a "base" folder (e.g. values vs values-es) will be used when the language does not match any of the provided alternatives.

Comment: it's giving error because you have not defined the context variable, so at your first activity you can write as bellow before setContentView(), 
Locale locale = new Locale("en_US");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
this works for me.

Answer (score 15):

Okay,

to make everything clear,
I realized `res/values` is a DEFAULT directory and the others are just "in case of language". So everything I had to do was to switch the english to /res/values and the other language goes to `res/values-es`

Answer (score 0):

You should define all languages you support using res folders, i.e `res/values`, `res/values-en`, `res/values-fr`.  The system will take care of everything else, you don't need any code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in an activity you can do:

`this.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);`

...to fix your error.
Otherwise you need to pass in the context.

Make sure you add the parenthesis at the end of `getApplicationContext()`. You didn't do so in your code.

Answer (score -1):

I've been in the same situation, my app was first created in portuguese (BR) so we went global and I had as second language En-Us, so my solution was creating a new language ( clicking in translation Editor + Brazil )... so I have my default language (Portuguese) second (English) third (Portuguese)

then I replaced the resource/ values to the english strings setting as default...